# Cannot send out packets by dev_queue_xmit()

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ip, netfilter

I want to capture packets in the NF_IP_LOCAL_OUT hook, and modify them a little bit. After that, I use `dev_queue_xmit()` to send the packets. Unfortunately, the packets cannot be successfully sent out though the the function returns 0. May I know how to fix this issue? Thank you!

```
static struct nf_hook_ops modify_ops;

static unsigned int modify(unsigned int hooknum, struct sk_buff * skb, const struct net_device * in, const struct net_device * out, int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *))
{

        struct sk_buff* nskb;
        struct iphdr* nip_hdr;
        unsigned int   nip_hdr_off;
        struct icmphdr *icmph = NULL;
        int ret = 0;
        struct net *net = NULL;

        nskb = skb_copy(skb, GFP_ATOMIC);
        if(nskb == NULL)
        {
                 printk("%s\n", "skb_copy return NULL");
                 return NF_ACCEPT;
        }


        if( ip_hdr(nskb)->protocol != IPPROTO_ICMP)
        {
                kfree_skb(nskb);
                return NF_ACCEPT;
        }

        nip_hdr = ip_hdr(nskb);   //nip_hdr = nskb->nh.iph;
        nip_hdr_off = nip_hdr->ihl << 2;

        nip_hdr->daddr = in_aton("192.168.1.1");
        nip_hdr->check = 0;
        nip_hdr->check = ip_fast_csum((unsigned char *)nip_hdr, nip_hdr->ihl);
        icmph = icmp_hdr(nskb);
        icmph->checksum = 0;
        icmph->checksum = in_cksum((unsigned short *)icmph,
                        ntohs(nip_hdr->tot_len) - sizeof(struct iphdr));

        nskb->csum = 0;
        nskb->csum = csum_partial((unsigned char *)(ntcp_hdr + ntcp_hdr_off),
                                          ntohs(nip_hdr->tot_len) -
        nip_hdr_off - ntcp_hdr_off, 0);
        nskb->ip_summed = CHECKSUM_NONE;
        nskb->pkt_type  = PACKET_OUTGOING; //PACKET_OTHERHOST;

        neth_hdr = (struct ethhdr *) skb_push(nskb, ETH_HLEN);
        skb_reset_mac_header(nskb);
        nskb->protocol = neth_hdr->h_proto = htons(ETH_P_IP);
        memcpy (neth_hdr->h_dest, DMAC, ETH_ALEN);
        memcpy (neth_hdr->h_source, SMAC, ETH_ALEN);
        nskb->dev = dev_get_by_name(&init_net,ETH);
        if(nskb->dev==NULL)
        {
            printk("%s\n", "dev_get_by_name return NULL");
            kfree_skb(nskb);
            return NF_ACCEPT;
        }

        dev_hold(nskb->dev);
        printk("%s\n", "dev_hold ok");
        dev_put(nskb->dev);

        ret = dev_queue_xmit(nskb);
        printk("ret:%d\n", ret);
        return NF_STOLEN;

}


static int __init init(void)
{
  int  ret = 0;
  modify_ops.hook = modify;
  modify_ops.hooknum = 3; //NF_IP_LOCAL_OUT;
  modify_ops.pf = PF_INET;
  modify_ops.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;

  ret = nf_register_hook(&modify_ops);
  if (ret < 0)
   {
     printk("%s\n", "can't modify skb hook!");
     return ret;
   }

    printk("%s\n", "insmod modify skb module");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit fini(void)
{
    nf_unregister_hook(&modify_ops);
    printk("%s\n", "remove modify skb module.");
}

module_init(init);
module_exit(fini);
```

Comment: Can you please let us know how the packets didn't get sent out? did you check using tcpDump or wireshark for instance? or did the kernel crash? or what exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The ICMP checksum was not set in the packet. The checksum was calculated, but put in `nskb->csum`, which is meaningless in this context.

Below is what I though was the problem:

At the time the `NF_IP_LOCAL_OUT` is called, the packet's MAC header wasn't set yet.
`dev_queue_xmit`, however, expects the MAC header to be in place.

Setting the MAC header (which may involve sending an ARP packet) is done in `ip_finish_output`, after the hook, and before calling `dev_queue_xmit`.

You shouldn't call `dev_queue_xmit`. If you can't simply return `NF_ACCEPT`, you need to reinject the packet (`nf_reinject`).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Actually, in the code, I set the MAC header. I think it should be okay to deliver packets by dev_queue_xmit.

Comment: You do indeed. I still think things would be smoother if you inject to the same place you took the packet (i.e. `nf_reinject`). Anyway, what about the ICMP checksum? `nskb->csum` doesn't set it.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I commented out the ICMP checksum and SKB cheksum by mistake. It seems ICMP packets can go through now. I corrected the code above. Thanks.

Comment: I added this explanation to the answer itself.